How a B-Tree index on a columnar table would look like?
Greenplum database supports B-tree index on append-optimized columnar tables which allows UPDATE operations as well . Even though it's not a recommended practice to have index on such tables(probably because they are intended for append-only and do fast sequential scans) for update operation, an index on distributing column reduces execution time drastically.
While traditionally a B-tree index on rowstore table holds the pointer to heap with offset value, how this will be implemented on a columnar table? If the table has N columns does each entry in index contain total N-1 pointers to each column blocks?

"Even though it's not a recommended practice to have index on such tables" - Who is not-recommending this, exactly? Please provide a source or citation, thanks.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum/7/greenplum-database/admin_guide-ddl-ddl-index.html i have verified this, columnar table plans always prefer seq scan over index scan while the same data on the normal tables performing index scan.

This answer is for PostgreSQL specifically.
A B-tree index on a table that uses columnar storage will look just like any other B-tree index. The leaf nodes reference a table row. In PostgreSQL, the APIs for a custom table access method and a custom index access method are independent. The link is in the "tuple identifier".
The question is how the column store implements a tuple ID. One approach is to have a separate column for that. Needless to say, collecting an individual table row from a column store is quite inefficient.

Oh thanks for pointing out about TID. So TID is where the implementation changes while B-tree holds TID irrespective of underlying table orientation. "One approach is to have a separate column for that" How this works?  I have read that columnar table itself implement an index like structure internally and hence there is no need to explicitly define an index.

Right, a tuple ID identifies a table row. I don't know how column stores organize their columns internally - I guess there might be different approaches.
